# Image class not showing when System.Drawing is referenced

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio, drawing

As you can see I have a reference in my project to System.Drawing. However, the Image class is not showing up for me. I can't even find the System.Drawing namespace. I'm using a .NET 4.6 with MVC4 in Visual Studio 2015. I'm wanting to use it just to do some image conversion on the server, but can't get the reference to work as it should for some reason.

Only place I reference the Image class since it was asked for. I can't show the company name though so that is the reason I'm picking out pieces. References for the file are shown below and it is included in the same file as this function. I've included hundreds of dll's in other projects before so I'm positive I didn't add it incorrectly.  Several others have been added to this project in the same manner, but just System.Drawing from Assemblies -> Framework like several others.

```
public static string CompressToBase64(XmlDocument document,  List<ChartInformation> charts)
{
    string report, test = document.OuterXml;
    using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var compressionStream = new ZipOutputStream(outStream))
        {
            compressionStream.PutNextEntry(new ZipEntry("Report.xml"));
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(document.OuterXml);
            compressionStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            
            if (charts != null)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < charts.Count; i++)
                {
                    compressionStream.PutNextEntry(new ZipEntry(charts[i].FileName + ".png"));
                    bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(charts[i].Base64Data);

                    Image image;
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                    {
                        image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                    }

                    compressionStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
            }
        }

        report = Convert.ToBase64String(outStream.ToArray());
    }

    return report;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show the code that isn't compiling?

Comment: I added what I can, I can't throw out a full set of code since I need to omit the company name which is sprinked throughout the code. I've tested pulling the class into other files with different namespaces and am positive this isn't a namespace issue. It is like it isn't actually pulling it in despite listing it like it has.

Also I'm trying to implement a feature but the code isn't finished yet naturally ... since i can't run it or test it.

Comment: Delete the question if you don't need it answered.

Comment: If you change those references to `Image` to fully qualified `System.Drawing.Image`, what is the compile error?

Comment: Also, unrelated to your question, when that `using` goes out of scope on `MemoryStream` it will make the `Image` that you loaded from it invalid.  An `Image` loaded from a stream requires the `Stream` to stay open (which I always thought was crazy)